# How to add new fields in wordpress custom theme options

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using "[Slightly Modded Options Framework](http://aquagraphite.com/2011/09/slightly-modded-options-framework/)" to give my clients a way to easily edit the theme. The code below is what I am using to grab a description of an image. I would like the client to be able to click "ADD" lets say to be able to add another description without me having to leave loads of empty text areas. I really am a novice with php so if anyone can help me out or point me in the right direction then I would be very happy, Thanks

```
$of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Textarea",
                        "desc"      => "Textarea description.",
                        "id"        => "example_textarea",
                        "std"       => "Default Text",
                        "type"      => "textarea"
                );
```

Comment: Create textarea using jquery while clicking on Add button

Comment: I did try that but i didnt know how to get the array id to be created

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Advanced custom field plugin for this feature. That more effective for creating Custom options for pages/posts.